# Factory for Spring Beans implementing interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

Considering a project of many entities, I have a service that requires to know the entity's type to execute a method. I created;

```
interface Service<T> {
  String myMethod(T entity)
  Class<T> getResponsibility()
```

And for example;

```
class FooService<Foo> {
  String myMethod(Foo entity) { return 'foo'; }
  Class<Foo> getResponsibility() { return Foo.class }
```

I wanted to create a factory to return the correct Bean (I'm using Spring Boot) to use, which I defined:

```
class ServiceFactory {
  List<Service<?>> services;
  
  @Autowired
  public ServiceFactory(List<Service<?>> services) {
    this.services = services;
  }

  Service getFor(Object entity) {
    // Simplified for comprehension purpose
    return this.services.stream().filter(service -> service.getResponsibility().equals(entity.getClass()).get();
}
```

This works, but I have a (sonar) warning saying that I should not make 'raw' use of `Service` as return type for my factory method. What is the correct way of achieving this ? Using a wildcard is another warning.

The goal is to have a factory that returns the correct Bean. Is the initial design wrong ?

Comment: You are calling get() without checking if the Service is present.

Comment: Yes @SimonMartinelli, the real code has a check and throws an exception, but I did not feel it relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing an object, pass the class itself and capture it as a method type parameter:

```
<T> Service<T> getFor(Class<T> type) {
```

You'd still get a warning because the injected list uses a wildcard:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> Service<T> getFor(Class<T> type) {
    // Simplified for comprehension purpose
    return (Service<T>) this.services.stream()
            .filter(service -> service.getResponsibility().equals(type))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```

You might be better off using [Spring's support for generics](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics) by injecting directly the specific service:

```
@Autowired
Service<Foo> fooService;
```

Comment: The list of autowired services is using a wildcard, how would that coexist with the method type parameter ? How would you write the body of the method ?

Comment: Just like your body but with this filter-predicate `filter(service -> type.equals(service.getResponsibility()))`. Then cast to `Service<T>` before returning.

Comment: @Madlemon That would produce an unchecked cast warning, am I missing something ?

Comment: I think you can safely suppress that warning. The type of service will always be correct and safe to cast since `getResponsibility()` can only return the exact type of the service.

Comment: @NathanBruissard Updated my answer. Indeed you're right, there is still a warning, but it's up to the responsibility method of the service to match the type.